# In search of a lightweight pdf viewer

Tags: pdf, documentviewer

I am looking for a lightweight pdf viewer ( commercial / free) for my windows application.
I presently display the pdf documents on a webbrowser with Adobe Reader Plug-ins.

### Background :

The problem i am having with Adobe Reader is the Loading time. To display a pdf document for the very first time, Adobe Reader nearly takes 15 seconds !! .The application when deployed on customer locations (usually run on Windows Embedded OS) the pdf viewing time is still worse, sometimes takes more than a minute.

Hence i need to find an alternative for Adobe Reader.

My simple requirements are :

1. Lightweight - viewer should initialise itself and load the pdf as
   fast as possible.
2. SVG support.

If anyone has any idea regarding such a tool. Kindly let me know

Regards
Srivatsa

Comment: Please mark as answered,based on which you find is the correct answer.This may help others.

Comment: Pdf.js is the definitive viewer.

Answer (score 2):

Try : [Foxit PDF SDK](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/sdk/)

Comment: Thanks i have requested for the Trial SDK. I shall try it and let u know if that did help

Answer (score 2):

Try SumatraPDF (Download full kit for MOZ plugin npPDFViewer.dll sorry there is NO IE.OCX)

For a  minimal install use with the portable executable in same directory and you can call via DDE or command line

Answer (score 1):

I think best light weight option for Windows is MuPDF for those who would rather not use any plugin in the Chrome.

http://mupdf.com/